# Delete shared memory with iprm in Linux fails

Tags: php, linux, ipc, shared-memory, ipcs

I'm working with shared memory and I am testing memory reference overflow. I have some problems in my code and I can't delete all memory segments
I'm trying like this:

```
ipcs -m
ipcrm -m 360448
ipcs -m
```

The memory segment never deletes

```
    ------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      bytes      nattch     status
0x00000000 360448     root       700        2484       2          dest
0x00000000 393218     root       700        8372       2          dest
0x00000000 425987     root       700        4416       2          dest
0x00000000 458756     root       700        2484       2          dest
0x00000000 491525     root       700        2400       2          dest
0x00000000 524294     root       700        12800      2          dest
0x00000000 557063     root       700        5800       2          dest
0x00000000 589832     root       700        144160     2          dest
0x00000000 622601     root       700        24672      2          dest
0x00000000 655370     root       700        34368      2          dest
0x00000000 688139     root       700        9996       2          dest
```

Comment: And this has what to do with `php`?

Comment: With php I'm trying delete with "shmop_delete"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
When the shared memory status is dest
first list all memory segment with ipcs -mp
then delete the memory segment with kill "lpid number"